# Using nested loops, populate a 2d array with associative first level keys and indexed row elements from two flat arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in PHP using a foreach loop.  Here is the code thus far:

```
$levels = array('low', 'medium', 'high');
$attributes = array('fat', 'quantity', 'ratio', 'label');
 
foreach ($levels as $key => $level):
    foreach ($attributes as $k =>$attribute):
        $variables[] = $attribute . '_' . $level;
    endforeach;
endforeach;

echo '<pre>' . print_r($levels,1) . '</pre>';   
echo '<pre>' . print_r($variables,1) . '</pre>';
```

The output from this code is a single dimension array; however, that is not the intent.  The desired array should look like this:

[image: OutputGoal]

How should the code be modified to achieve the goal?

Comment: Are you trying to combine two arrays into a single array, or create a new array from the data in those two arrays?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're aaalmost there. Just add the level to the array creation :)

```
$levels = array('low', 'medium', 'high');
$attributes = array('fat', 'quantity', 'ratio', 'label');

foreach ($levels as $key => $level):
       foreach ($attributes as $k =>$attribute):
             $variables[$level][] = $attribute . '_' . $level; // changed $variables[] to $variables[$level][]
       endforeach;
endforeach;

echo '<pre>' . print_r($levels,1) . '</pre>';   
echo '<pre>' . print_r($variables,1) . '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [low] => Array
        (
            [0] => fat_low
            [1] => quantity_low
            [2] => ratio_low
            [3] => label_low
        )

    [medium] => Array
        (
            [0] => fat_medium
            [1] => quantity_medium
            [2] => ratio_medium
            [3] => label_medium
        )

    [high] => Array
        (
            [0] => fat_high
            [1] => quantity_high
            [2] => ratio_high
            [3] => label_high
        )

)
```

Comment: I have this  problem.
I need someting like that out of a foreach.

`$arrOptions = array(
 array( 
                 'value' => 'value1', 
                  'label' =>  'label1'
              )
);`

Foreach value and label is the same variable.
What i try is
`$arrOptions = array();
   foreach($daterange as $option) {
       $arrOptions[value] = $option->format;
       $arrOptions[label] = $option->format;
    }`

Answer (score 6):

```
$levels = ['low', 'medium', 'high'];
$attributes = ['fat', 'quantity', 'ratio', 'label'];

$result = [];
foreach ($levels as $level) {
    $result[$level] = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $result[$level][] = $attribute . '_' . $level;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: If you are editing, this code-only answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: I reformatted code in my own seven-years-old answer. I don't have anything to add. :)

Comment: You could explain how the OP's code was failing and/or how your code manages to produce the expected output structure.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk thank you for supplying this answer; it got me out of a coding nadir converting a multi-dimensional array to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

```
$levels = ['low', 'medium', 'high'];
$attributes = ['fat', 'quantity', 'ratio', 'label'];

foreach ($levels as $level) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $variables[$level][] = $attribute . '_' . $level;
   }
}

print_r($variables);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/xlvZ2W