# Creating a valid JSON output from PHP for loops

Tags: php, json, for-loop

Having some trouble getting a valid JSON output from a php for loop, here is my JSON:

```
[{"title":"One Colour ($2.45)","price":"($2.45)"},{"title":"Two Colours ($3.35)","price":"($3.35)"},{"title":"Three Colours ($4.25)","price":"($4.25)"}],[{"title":"One Colour ($2.45)","price":"($2.45)"},{"title":"Two Colours ($3.35)","price":"($3.35)"},{"title":"Three Colours ($4.25)","price":"($4.25)"},{"title":"One Colour ($3.05)","price":"($3.05)"},{"title":"Two Colours ($4.35)","price":"($4.35)"},{"title":"Three Colours ($5.75)","price":"($5.75)"}],
```

And here is my php loop that creates the json output

```
foreach ( $product_addons as $addon ) {


    foreach ( $addon['options'] as $option ) :

        $loop ++;
        switch ($qty) {
            case ($qty < 20):
                $price = $option['price'] > 0 ? ' (' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ) ) . ')' : '';
                $title = strip_tags($option['label']. $price);


            break;
            case ($qty > 20 && $qty < 35):
                $price = $option['discount'] > 0 ? ' (' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['discount'] ) ) . ')' : '';
                $title = strip_tags($option['label']. $price);
            break;


        }

        $select_text[] = array( 
                'title' => trim($title),
                'price' => trim(strip_tags($price)),
        );



    endforeach;
    echo json_encode($select_text).",";
}
```

The problem I am getting now is that the JSON output is now valid and I cant quite figure out how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out by looking at this thread:
[create multidimensional array using a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135685/create-multidimensional-array-using-a-foreach-loop)

Basically all I needed to do was to use the index of the first foreach loop in a multidimensional array. Here is my final code:

```
foreach ( $product_addons as $key => $addon ) {

    foreach ( $addon['options'] as $option ) :

        $loop ++;
        switch ($qty) {
            case ($qty < 20):
                $price = $option['price'] > 0 ? ' (' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ) ) . ')' : '';
                $title = strip_tags($option['label']. $price);

            break;
            case ($qty > 20 && $qty < 35):
                $price = $option['discount'] > 0 ? ' (' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['discount'] ) ) . ')' : '';
                $title = strip_tags($option['label']. $price);
            break;

        }

        $title = trim($title);

         // Add in your custom fields or WP fields that you want
         $locations[$key][] = array(
           'title' => $title,

         );

    endforeach; 
}
echo json_encode($locations);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem according to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is

> Multiple JSON root elements

The solution is puttin everything in 1 embedding aray:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "title":"One Colour ($2.45)",
         "price":"($2.45)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Two Colours ($3.35)",
         "price":"($3.35)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Three Colours ($4.25)",
         "price":"($4.25)"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "title":"One Colour ($2.45)",
         "price":"($2.45)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Two Colours ($3.35)",
         "price":"($3.35)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Three Colours ($4.25)",
         "price":"($4.25)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"One Colour ($3.05)",
         "price":"($3.05)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Two Colours ($4.35)",
         "price":"($4.35)"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Three Colours ($5.75)",
         "price":"($5.75)"
      }
   ]
]
```

and 2: on line `echo json_encode($select_text).",";` why would you add a trailing comma?

Comment: Thanks for that - I used your advice and looked at another thread to come up with a solution